# Is there a way to use custom fonts in WordPress without Elementor Pro?

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to use a personalised font for my website on WordPress with Elementor Builder.

I imported files in wp-content/themes/fonts and modified the style.css. The code is okay, but font is not showing in Elementor.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'la_luxes_scriptregular';
    src: url('http://www.lamorecesttout.com/wp-content/themes/solene/webfonts/la_luxes_script-webfont.eot');
    src: url('http://www.lamorecesttout.com/wp-content/themes/solene/webfonts/la_luxes_script-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('http://www.lamorecesttout.com/wp-content/themes/solene/webfonts/la_luxes_script-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('http://www.lamorecesttout.com/wp-content/themes/solene/webfonts/la_luxes_script-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('http://www.lamorecesttout.com/wp-content/themes/solene/webfonts/la_luxes_script-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('http://www.lamorecesttout.com/wp-content/themes/solene/webfonts/la_luxes_script-webfont.svg#la_luxes_scriptregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

Do I have to get Elementor Pro to use custom fonts? Any solutions?

Thank you.

I don't have Elementor Pro.

My theme is: Solene (themeforest)
PHP version: 7.4
Hosting: Easyhost

Answer (score 0):

Acording to Elementors own site you have done the first 3 steps that I can see but have you done:

> 4. Configure the elements that will use this font by adding them to the same stylesheet.

If you have done this then I do not know the issue. You could always try the other option that they suggest here: https://elementor.com/blog/custom-fonts/